# Let $Y$~$Gamma(a,b)$ with PDF $f(y)$= $y^{a-1}e^{-y/b}/\gamma(a)b^a$; $y>0$ For $a>1$, show that the mode of $Y$ is $(a-1)b$.

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables, gamma-distribution

Suppose that $Y$ follows a gamma distribution with parameters $a$ and $b$. That
is,

$f(y)$= $y^{a-1}e^{-y/b}/\gamma(a)b^a$; $y>0$

For $a>1$, show that the mode of $Y$ is $(a-1)b$.

My working:

I know that the mode is the value of $y$ where its density is maximized; hence for given $f(y)$ I have:

$f^{'}(y) = 0$ and I solve for values of $y$. The trouble is when I put the value of $\gamma(a)$ in the given $f(y)$ and take its derivative by applying quotient rule the numerator becomes complicated for me to handle it since there is improper integral involved. Can any one help me. I will appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
f(y)&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(a)b^a}y^{a -1}e^{-\frac yb}\\
f'(y)&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(a)b^a}\frac d{dy}y^{a-1}e^{-\frac yb}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)b^a}\left[(a -1)y^{a-2}e^{-\frac yb}-\frac 1by^{a-1}e^{-\frac yb}\right]\\
&=\frac{e^{-\frac yb}y^{a-2}}{\Gamma(a)b^a}\left((a-1)-\frac1by\right)=0\\
(a-1)-\frac 1by&= 0\longrightarrow -\frac1by=-(a-1)\longrightarrow y=(a-1)b
\end{align*}
Note that $\Gamma(a)b^a$ is just a normalizing constant, and does not depend on $y$. The definition of the gamma function does not have to be used.

Comment: Yes you are right. I didn't observe that gamma function depends on $a$ not $y$ so it will be treated as a constant while differentiating w.r.t $y$